# Entity Framework giving ObjectDisposed Exception

Tags: vb.net, entity-framework

I'm using EF to make a Binding on a DataGrid on WPF. I'm getting ObjectDisposed Exception when I try to get a set ob objects out of the model.

The model is composed of 4 tables:

[image]

The exception occurs on this method

```
 Public Function usuariosActivos() As List(Of equipo)
    Using ctx As perfpruebaEntities = New perfpruebaEntities

        Return (From e In ctx.equipo
                Where (e.estado_id_est = 3)
                Select e).ToList
    End Using
End Function
```

When I declare the context without Using statement, everything works. What could it be?? I've been trying in different ways, but to no avail. Could it be related to the relationships??

Comment: Yes, it's caused by the related classes as they are lazy loaded.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's most likely caused by lazy loading.  Please try the following:

```
Public Function usuariosActivos() As List(Of equipo)
    Using ctx As perfpruebaEntities = New perfpruebaEntities

        Return (From e In ctx.equipo
                             .Include("depto")
                             .Include("estado")
                             .Include("perfil")
                Where (e.estado_id_est = 3)
                Select e).ToList
    End Using
End Function
```

Comment: the .Include part was the missing part. Thanks